# Swift Firebase metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Just updated my cocoa pods thus updating firebase. This line of code is the old way, which is wrong now:

```
let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
let values: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["download_url": downloadURL]
```

The following code is the correct way now to extract the URL string. Yet, I need help on how I can put that string into my array to save to firebase.

```
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
    if error != nil {
     print(error!.localizedDescription)
       return
    }
    let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString

})

let values: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["download_url": downloadURL]
```

**How I save "values" as a child**

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
let path = databaseRef.child("posts").child((self.loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId()
path.setValue(values) { (error, ref) -> Void in
    if error != nil {
        print("error saving post in db")
    } else {
        let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("posts_requests").child((self.loggedInUser?.uid)!).child(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid").value as! String).child(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "uid").value as! String).child(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "imageID").value as! String)
        storageRef.delete(completion: { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print("Successful Delete")
            }
        })

    }
}
```

**Using the answers below...**

When I use the submitted answers below I get a print out saying "User does not have permission to access gs://shoppeer-e7270.appspot.com/(null)." All I am trying to accomplish is grabbing that URL string and adding it to my "values" which is a Dictionary.

**My full code for image upload as well as saving as a child**

```
        let photosRef = storage.reference().child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!)
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("Businesses")
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let photoRef = photosRef.child("\(uid)")
    let postID = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId().key
    var downloadURLSting = String()

    photoRef.child("\(imageName)").putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("there was an error")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            // store downloadURL
            storage.reference().downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString

                let values: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["uid": uid, "caption": caption ?? "", "download_url": downloadURL, "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp(), "businessName":loggedInUserData?["businessName"] as! String, "businessStreet":loggedInUserData?["businessStreet"] as! String, "businessCity":loggedInUserData?["businessCity"] as! String, "businessState":loggedInUserData?["businessState"] as! String, "businessZIP":loggedInUserData?["businessZIP"] as! String, "businessPhone":loggedInUserData?["businessPhone"] as! String, "businessWebsite":loggedInUserData?["businessWebsite"] as! String, "businessLatitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLatitude"] as! String, "businessLongitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLongitude"] as! String, "facebookURL":loggedInUserData?["facebookURL"] as! String, "twitterURL":loggedInUserData?["twitterURL"] as! String, "instagramURL":loggedInUserData?["instagramURL"] as! String, "googleURL":loggedInUserData?["googleURL"] as! String, "yelpURL":loggedInUserData?["yelpURL"] as! String, "foursquareURL":loggedInUserData?["foursquareURL"] as! String, "snapchatURL":loggedInUserData?["snapchatURL"] as! String, "imageID": imageName, "postID": postID]

                // store downloadURL at database
                let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
                let path = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId()
                path.setValue(values) { (error, ref) -> Void in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("error saving post in db")
                    } else {
                        // reset caption field
                        self.descriptionTextView.text = ""
                        // reset placeholder image
                        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "filterPlaceholder")
                        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                        let viewConrolller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Business Profile") as! UITabBarController
                        self.present(viewConrolller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

**This works just downloadURL string is nil**

```
 let photosRef = storage.reference().child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!)
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("Businesses")
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let photoRef = photosRef.child("\(uid)")
    let postID = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId().key
    photoRef.child("\(imageName)").putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("there was an error")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            // store downloadURL
            photoRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
                if error != nil {

                    guard let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString else { return }

                    let values: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["uid": uid, "caption": caption ?? "", "download_url": downloadURL, "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp(), "businessName":loggedInUserData?["businessName"] as! String, "businessStreet":loggedInUserData?["businessStreet"] as! String, "businessCity":loggedInUserData?["businessCity"] as! String, "businessState":loggedInUserData?["businessState"] as! String, "businessZIP":loggedInUserData?["businessZIP"] as! String, "businessPhone":loggedInUserData?["businessPhone"] as! String, "businessWebsite":loggedInUserData?["businessWebsite"] as! String, "businessLatitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLatitude"] as! String, "businessLongitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLongitude"] as! String, "facebookURL":loggedInUserData?["facebookURL"] as! String, "twitterURL":loggedInUserData?["twitterURL"] as! String, "instagramURL":loggedInUserData?["instagramURL"] as! String, "googleURL":loggedInUserData?["googleURL"] as! String, "yelpURL":loggedInUserData?["yelpURL"] as! String, "foursquareURL":loggedInUserData?["foursquareURL"] as! String, "snapchatURL":loggedInUserData?["snapchatURL"] as! String, "imageID": imageName, "postID": postID]

                    // store downloadURL at database
                    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
                    let path = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId()
                    path.setValue(values) { (error, ref) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("error saving post in db")
                        } else {
                            // reset caption field
                            self.descriptionTextView.text = ""
                            // reset placeholder image
                            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "filterPlaceholder")
                            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                            let viewConrolller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Business Profile") as! UITabBarController
                            self.present(viewConrolller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    print("error")
                    return
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`values` is a `Dictionary`, not an `Array`, but if you want to add `downloadURL` to it, you'll need to do that inside the completion handler of `storageRef.downloadURL(completion:)`, since that's an asynchronous method.

```
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
    if error != nil {
     print(error!.localizedDescription)
       return
    }
    let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString
    let values: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["download_url": downloadURL]
})
```

Comment: right, yet I take "values" and am saving it as a child in firebase, I will show in my edit. Will this still work how you are explaining?

Comment: Since it is a asynchronous method, I believe I won't be able to access "values"

Comment: @LukasBimba you just need to move all method calls where you need access to `values` inside the completion handler. You're right, outside the completion handler you cannot access values returned from async methods, but that's how async execution work, you can't do anything about it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have a few view controllers with this type of functionality so I need to make edits before I can compile my project and test this. Will give a update after I am finished. Thank you again

Comment: This code is used to create and save posts, when I try to save a post to the database a print out is "User does not have permission to access gs://shoppeer-e7270.appspot.com/(null)."

Comment: @LukasBimba which line of code is causing this error?

Comment: I added a edit which works now, just the download url string is nil

Comment: Your code makes downloadURL return nil, not sure why

Comment: @LukasBimba your if statement checking the error is wrong. You try downloading the image if there was a networking error. You should change `if error != nil {

                    guard let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString else { return }` to `if error == nil, let downloadURL = url {...`. So it's actually _your_ code that makes `downloadURL` `nil`, not mine :)

Answer (score 1):

The download URL is only available **inside** the completion handler.

```
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
    if error != nil {
     print(error!.localizedDescription)
       return
    }
    let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString
    let values: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["download_url": downloadURL]

    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let path = databaseRef.child("posts").child((self.loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId()
    path.setValue(values) { (error, ref) -> Void in
        ...
```

Comment: When I use the code below I get a print out "User does not have permission to access gs://shoppeer-e7270.appspot.com/(null)."