# Swift Firebase save downloadURL string

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I updated my firebase code because they changed "metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString" into the code I will post below. My problem is that I need to save the downloadURL string with the rest of the post's information. Since it is an asynchronous method, I cannot access the string outside of the call, and when I try to put my ".setValue" within the call, it simple doesn't work. Here is my previous question but no answers regarding this issue : [Swift Firebase metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52611994/swift-firebase-metadata-downloadurl-absolutestring)

```
let photosRef = storage.reference().child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!)
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("Businesses")
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let photoRef = photosRef.child("\(uid)")
    let postID = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId().key
    var downloadURLSting = String()

    photoRef.child("\(imageName)").putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("there was an error")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            // store downloadURL


            storage.reference().downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString

            })

            let values: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["uid": uid, "caption": caption ?? "", "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp(), "businessName":loggedInUserData?["businessName"] as! String, "businessStreet":loggedInUserData?["businessStreet"] as! String, "businessCity":loggedInUserData?["businessCity"] as! String, "businessState":loggedInUserData?["businessState"] as! String, "businessZIP":loggedInUserData?["businessZIP"] as! String, "businessPhone":loggedInUserData?["businessPhone"] as! String, "businessWebsite":loggedInUserData?["businessWebsite"] as! String, "businessLatitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLatitude"] as! String, "businessLongitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLongitude"] as! String, "facebookURL":loggedInUserData?["facebookURL"] as! String, "twitterURL":loggedInUserData?["twitterURL"] as! String, "instagramURL":loggedInUserData?["instagramURL"] as! String, "googleURL":loggedInUserData?["googleURL"] as! String, "yelpURL":loggedInUserData?["yelpURL"] as! String, "foursquareURL":loggedInUserData?["foursquareURL"] as! String, "snapchatURL":loggedInUserData?["snapchatURL"] as! String, "imageID": imageName, "postID": postID]

            // store downloadURL at database
            let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
            let path = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId()
            path.setValue(values) { (error, ref) -> Void in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error saving post in db")
                } else {
                    // reset caption field
                    self.descriptionTextView.text = ""
                    // reset placeholder image
                    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "filterPlaceholder")
                    MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                    let viewConrolller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Business Profile") as! UITabBarController
                    self.present(viewConrolller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Security Rules**

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
}
}
}
```

**This code works just "downloadURL" is returning nil**

```
let photosRef = storage.reference().child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!)
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("Businesses")
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let photoRef = photosRef.child("\(uid)")
    let postID = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId().key
    photoRef.child("\(imageName)").putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metaData,error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("there was an error")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        } else {
            // store downloadURL
            photoRef.downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
                if error != nil {

                    guard let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString else { return }

                    let values: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["uid": uid, "caption": caption ?? "", "download_url": downloadURL, "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp(), "businessName":loggedInUserData?["businessName"] as! String, "businessStreet":loggedInUserData?["businessStreet"] as! String, "businessCity":loggedInUserData?["businessCity"] as! String, "businessState":loggedInUserData?["businessState"] as! String, "businessZIP":loggedInUserData?["businessZIP"] as! String, "businessPhone":loggedInUserData?["businessPhone"] as! String, "businessWebsite":loggedInUserData?["businessWebsite"] as! String, "businessLatitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLatitude"] as! String, "businessLongitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLongitude"] as! String, "facebookURL":loggedInUserData?["facebookURL"] as! String, "twitterURL":loggedInUserData?["twitterURL"] as! String, "instagramURL":loggedInUserData?["instagramURL"] as! String, "googleURL":loggedInUserData?["googleURL"] as! String, "yelpURL":loggedInUserData?["yelpURL"] as! String, "foursquareURL":loggedInUserData?["foursquareURL"] as! String, "snapchatURL":loggedInUserData?["snapchatURL"] as! String, "imageID": imageName, "postID": postID]

                    // store downloadURL at database
                    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
                    let path = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId()
                    path.setValue(values) { (error, ref) -> Void in
                        if error != nil {
                            print("error saving post in db")
                        } else {
                            // reset caption field
                            self.descriptionTextView.text = ""
                            // reset placeholder image
                            self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "filterPlaceholder")
                            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                            let viewConrolller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Business Profile") as! UITabBarController
                            self.present(viewConrolller, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    print("error")
                    return
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work" when placing the setValue inside of the downloadUrl callback? Do you get an error?

Comment: Instead try writing the database entirely inside the completion for downloadURL, when all the information is available to write.

Comment: When I do so I get "User does not have permission to access gs://shoppeer-e7270.appspot.com/(null)."

Comment: @DougStevenson how would I access "downloadURL" outside of ".putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metaData,error) in" I've tried putting my "Database.setValue" inside and get the error "User does not have permission to access gs://shoppeer-e7270.appspot.com/(null)."

Comment: Now you have a whole different problem, maybe with security rules.

Comment: I just added my security rules, they are how all other answers say they should be

Comment: @DougStevenson any way I can extract the string from the asynchronous method? I need to have the downloadURL with my "values" when creating and saving my post

Comment: @DougStevenson I posted a edit that works, just downloadURL is returning nil maybe you can help me understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely because your variables aren't in the same scope. What happens when you try this instead?

```
photoRef.child("\(imageName)").putData(data!, metadata: nil) { (metaData,error) in
    if let error = error {
        print("there was an error")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    } 

    storage.reference().downloadURL(completion: {(url, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            let downloadURL = url?.absoluteString

            let values: Dictionary<String, Any> = ["uid": uid, "caption": caption ?? "", "timestamp": ServerValue.timestamp(), "businessName":loggedInUserData?["businessName"] as! String, "businessStreet":loggedInUserData?["businessStreet"] as! String, "businessCity":loggedInUserData?["businessCity"] as! String, "businessState":loggedInUserData?["businessState"] as! String, "businessZIP":loggedInUserData?["businessZIP"] as! String, "businessPhone":loggedInUserData?["businessPhone"] as! String, "businessWebsite":loggedInUserData?["businessWebsite"] as! String, "businessLatitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLatitude"] as! String, "businessLongitude":loggedInUserData?["businessLongitude"] as! String, "facebookURL":loggedInUserData?["facebookURL"] as! String, "twitterURL":loggedInUserData?["twitterURL"] as! String, "instagramURL":loggedInUserData?["instagramURL"] as! String, "googleURL":loggedInUserData?["googleURL"] as! String, "yelpURL":loggedInUserData?["yelpURL"] as! String, "foursquareURL":loggedInUserData?["foursquareURL"] as! String, "snapchatURL":loggedInUserData?["snapchatURL"] as! String, "imageID": imageName, "postID": postID]

        let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
        let path = databaseRef.child("posts").child((loggedInUser?.uid)!).childByAutoId()
        path.setValue(values) { (error, ref) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print("error saving post in db")
            } else {
                // reset caption field
                self.descriptionTextView.text = ""
                // reset placeholder image
                self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "filterPlaceholder")
                MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
                let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Business Profile") as! UITabBarController
                self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }

    })        
}
```

Comment: I get this "User does not have permission to access gs://shoppeer-e7270.appspot.com/(null)."